# Is $_GET available in all created classes?

Tags: php, get, eval

I do one request and my URL has a parameter like this `.../index.php?customer=abc`

In `index.php`'s class `$_GET['customer']` is available.

There are multiple other classes being created then.

Finally in `somefile.php` containing some different class `someClass`, `$_GET['customer']` is no more available.

I am forced to use a framework that uses a form that `eval()`s PHP code on button click.

`new TDynButton($body, "login", ... , "\$this->win->doLogin();");`

In`doLogin()` there is no `$_GET['customer']`. Cannot understand why. Is it possible if this framework uses `action=GET` in the background that I am losing my `$_GET`? Im totally lost.

Thanks.

Comment: Wait, eval()? When a button is clicked? Eh.. This sounds like a very serious security issue. I have been programming in PHP for over 7 years now, and I have never ever used eval()..

Comment: Yes this framework is weird but I need to use it for this project. I dont want to discuss `eval()` but `$_GET`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach would be to give the information in $_GET['customer'] to the instatiated object by passing it in the constructor and store it in a private member. This way you have the information needed and no direct access to $_GET is nessessary. This is anyway a better design I think.

Comment: Thanks. I go with the member attempt. I now access it with `if(isset($_GET['cust'])) $this->strGetParam = $_GET['cust'];` and then in the button eval `\$this->win->doLogin(\$this->win->strGetParam);`

Comment: Eval has two major disadvantages. First, the input must be valid. Otherwise php breaks execution. Second it can be a huge security problem. Make sure to keep these facts in mind. I would not directly send user input into eval(). You should at least validate it somehow. What if your user inputs "exit();"?

Comment: Yes, I additionally use `preg_match("/^[a-z0-9_-]+$/i", $this->strGetParam)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $_GET is a superglobal variable that is available in all PHP scripts.

And yes, generally, framework convert/sanitaze the GET/POST arrays and clears them.

Answer (score 0):

$_GET is a global variable that will be available throughout the script you use it in. You have to pass it to the script, though - such as somefile.php?customer=peter